# Format not a string literal

Tags: ios

I would appreciate understanding how to rewrite this line of code to eliminate the compiler warning. The code is:

```
if (string == nil)
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:nil];
```

The warning is:

```
Format not a string literal and no format arguments.
```

I found answers pertaining to NSLog, but not to NSException.

JAL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error applies to anything which expects a format string. You simply need to replace `nil` with `@""`, as in:

```
[NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the compiler expects a format string(of type @"%@"), not a string literal(constant string) for the format parameter. Try giving an empty string @"" it should work.

```
[NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@""];
```

This is better explained [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2010/Jul/msg00019.html)